# Destructor in template class gives an error

Tags: c++, templates

I have an `Array` template class which looks like this

```
template <typename T>

class Array {
   private:
    T *_array;
    int _arrSize;

   public:
    Array<T>() : _arrSize(0) {
        T *a = new T[0];
        this->_array = a;
    };

    Array<T>(unsigned int n) : _arrSize(n) {
        T *a = new T[n];
        this->_array = a;
    };

    Array<T>(Array<T> const &copy) : _array(copy._array), _arrSize(copy._arrSize) {
        *this = copy;
        return;
    };

    template <typename G>
    Array<T> &operator=(Array<G> const &rhs) {
        if (&rhs != this) {
            Array<T> tmp(rhs);
            std::swap(*this, tmp);
        }
        return *this;
    };

    ~Array<T>() {
        delete[] this->_array;
        this->_array = NULL;
    };

    T &getArray() const {
        return this->_array;
    }
```

Which works fine until I try to do the assignment

```
Array<int> g;
Array<int> i(3);
i[1] = 99;
g = i;
```

then I get an error

> ```
> array(99457,0x10f5f25c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc390c02aa0: pointer being freed was not allocated
> array(99457,0x10f5f25c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
> zsh: abort      ./array
> ```

which obviously comes from the destructor here

```
delete[] this->_array;
```

I'm not sure how to write the assignment operator correctly to avoid this error.

Comment: @MaxLanghof the problem exists even if I don't call the operator from the copy constructor

Comment: Your copy constructor makes a "flat" copy, i.e. it copies pointer to array. Afterwards, you have two instances pointing to the same allocated array. If first is deleted, you get a dangling pointer in 2nd instance. If you delete 2nd instance -> BAM!

Comment: Side note: you don't need to repeat template parameters inside template class (i. e. `Array() { /*...*/ }` suffices).

Comment: Hint: Only your `Array(int)` constructor allocates a new usable `T*` array. If you **copy** construct or **copy** assign, you need to have **two** usable `T*` arrays afterwards, and neither your copy constructor nor your copy assignment operator creates a new usable `T*` array in any way. Also, you do not copy the stored data at any point - there is no way around doing that when you want to actually copy.

Comment: Concerning your copy assingment... It uses the copy constructor inside and hence "inherits" the wrong behavior of it.

Comment: @Scheff how do I work around that, I'm blank as to how to procceed

Comment: Actually, what you try to implement already exists, it is called `std::vector`...

Comment: You have to allocate with `new` in your copy constructor as well as you did it in the other.

Comment: @Aconcagua I know, this is a school project to make us understand fundamentals

Comment: The alternative would be to have something like a ref counter which is stored with array but ... Try the deep copy first. ;-)

Comment: `this->_array = NULL;` is pretty meaningless in the destructor... Apart from, you should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`).

Comment: @Scheff I just read about deep copy and I think it should help

Comment: your copy ctor if you remove `*this = copy;` would be equal to compiler generated one, and neither is correct. This assignment does not make it better  just more complicated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how do I work around that, I'm blank as to how to procceed

As mentioned in the comments already: you need a deep copy.

```
Array(Array const& copy) : _array(new T[copy._arrSize]), _arrSize(copy._arrSize)
// create a NEW array here:           ^
{
    //now you need to copy the data:
    std::copy(copy._array, copy._array + _arrSize, _array);
    // or implement a loop, if you are not allowed to use std::copy
};
```

You might additionally implement move semantics:

```
Array(Array&& other)    : _array(other._array), _arrSize(other._arrSize)
// now this object 'steals' the data  ^
{
    // now this is the owner of the data – but you still need to make sure that
    // the data is not owned TWICE, so:
    other._array = nullptr; // I'd prefer this over an empty array – but you should
                            // adjust the other constructor then as well
                            // side note: you CAN safely delete a nullptr, so no
                            // special handling in destructor necessary
    other.arrSize = 0;
};
```

Actually, you can have it a bit simpler:

```
Array(Array&& other)    : Array()
// constructor delegation  ^
// (creates an EMPTY Array)
{
    // and now you can just:
    std::swap(*this, other)
};
```

Another variant (thanks, JeJo, for the hint):

```
Array(Array&& other)
    : _array(std::exchange(other._array, nullptr)),
      _arrSize(std::exchange(other._arrSize, 0))
{ };
```

Comment: Using `std::swap` inside assignment operator probably problematic as well - it will use assignment internally making this recursive.

Comment: @Slava Why should it be problematic? In contrast, it is fine. You create a temporary as a copy of the object to be assigned. By swapping, you make sure that the temporary receives the contents of `this` and will safely destroy them, so you needn't care for explicitly.

Comment: @Aconcagua I believe by default swap implemented as : `T tmp(a); a = b; b = tmp;`, so you call `operator=` from `operator=`

Comment: @Slava Good point... But then turn it round: Implement `operator=` directly and the copy constructor in terms of assignment: `Array(Array const& other) : Array() { *this = other; }`